# GameCard value recognition gives wrong result with AForge.NET

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-recognition, aforge

Actually I'm using `AForge.NET` to recognize `suit` and `value` from a gamecard.

Here is a snippet where I decide which `suit/value` is there:

```
public static CardTemplateIdentifier GetBestMatchingIdentifier(this List<CardTemplateIdentifier> templates, Bitmap bitmap)
{
    float maxSimilar = 0f;
    CardTemplateIdentifier result = null;
    foreach (var template in templates)
    {
        // Identify similarity between template and bmp
        ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0);
        TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(bitmap, template.Sample);

        // If the currently tested template fits better than the best one so far,
        // set the value as the identified card value
        if (matchings.Length > 0 && matchings[0].Similarity > maxSimilar)
        {
            maxSimilar = matchings[0].Similarity;
            result = template;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

`CardTemplateIdentifier` contains a list with all possible cards and their comparism sample.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
...

Now If trying to recognize the images, I can not rely on this being reliably recognized: Sometimes the scaling of the images differs from the one I made the sample. Or the font has got less thicknes, see example below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I think I'm on the wrong way to detect the values from the images. Is there a better or convience way how to solve this problem?